# Change height of CKEditor (per profile) without using WYSIWYG Module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

**Problem**

How can I change the height of the CKEditor window without using the solution outlined [here](https://drupal.org/node/1012050) which requires the WYSIWYG module. I can't spot where the height is defined in the CK module.

Ideally I'd like to be able to set it per profile and I'd prefer not to add an extra module if possible.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Do you want a different height per profile (so each user has a different height) or per role?

Comment: @FelixEve Either per user role, or just per CKEditor profile type (So full is a different height from filtered). At the moment I've just been switching it with firebug, but it's not really an option for everyone else.

Comment: How you installed CKEditor in the first place? Custom code, some module other than WYSIWYG module? Or maybe some hack at the theme level (I know, sounds weird, but seen that once)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

The patch in [this thread on DO](https://www.drupal.org/node/507696) fixes this issue.

---

Looking at the ckeditor demo on [this page](http://ckeditor.com/demo) it is possible to change the height of the editor with css alone.

The div .cke_contents has an element style setting the height to 300px, however a rule in the stylesheet marked as important would overrule this.

So, if you can add the roles of the user as a classes of say the body, then you could include:

```
.role1 .cke_contents {
    height: 400px !important;
}
.role2 .cke_contents {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Alternatively there may be a class added by the CKEditor profile type that you could use.